# Getting Exception

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I'm getting the following exception when calling 'GetProjectItemSummariesQuery' against my RIA Service. The weird thing is that it only happens once every four or five times I call the function.

```
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException: Load operation failed for query 'GetProjectItemSummaries'. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.<>c__DisplayClass1b.<Load>b__17(Object )
```

**Edits:**

I placed a try/catch in both the service that is being called and the calling function.  They caught nothing.

Comment: Are you returning a large amount of results (>5,000)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Configure WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342%28VS.100%29.aspx) and try to catch what's really going on.

Answer (score 0):

A faulty set SortDescriptor or FilterDescriptor could produce the same error