# Blowfish last block incomplete in decryption

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, encryption, blowfish

I have a exeption last block incomplete in decryption in only decryption, encrypt its work perfect. How fix this?

I use bouncy castle.

This is the code that i found [here](http://elian.co.uk/post/2009/07/29/Bouncy-Castle-CSharp.aspx)

```
 namespace BlowFishCS

  {
     public class BCEngine
    {
    private readonly Encoding _encoding;
    private readonly IBlockCipher _blockCipher;
    private PaddedBufferedBlockCipher _cipher;
    private IBlockCipherPadding _padding;

    public BCEngine(IBlockCipher blockCipher, Encoding encoding)
    {
        _blockCipher = blockCipher;
        _encoding = encoding;
    }

    public BCEngine()
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }

    public void SetPadding(IBlockCipherPadding padding)
    {
        if (padding != null)
            _padding = padding;
    }

    public string Encrypt(string plain, string key)
    {
        byte[] result = BouncyCastleCrypto(true, _encoding.GetBytes(plain), key);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
    }

    public string Decrypt(string cipher, string key)
    {
        //cipher = cipher.Replace(' ', '+');
        byte[] result = BouncyCastleCrypto(false, Convert.FromBase64String(cipher), key);
        return _encoding.GetString(result);
    }




    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="forEncrypt"></param>
    /// <param name="input"></param>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="CryptoException"></exception>


    private byte[] BouncyCastleCrypto(bool forEncrypt, byte[] input, string key)
    {

        try
        {

            _cipher = _padding == null ?
        new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(_blockCipher) :
        new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(_blockCipher, _padding);

            // this line will make sure keyByte is 16 bytes long
            byte[] keyByte = _encoding.GetBytes(key);

            _cipher.Init(forEncrypt, new KeyParameter(keyByte));

            return _cipher.DoFinal(input);
        }
        catch (Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.CryptoException ex)
        {
            throw new CryptoException(ex.Message); <here is exception last block incomplete in decryption
        }
    }
}

}
```

I use this encoding and functions.

```
    static Encoding _encoding = Encoding.ASCII; 
    static Pkcs7Padding pkcs = new Pkcs7Padding();
    static IBlockCipherPadding _padding = pkcs;

public static string Encryption(string plain, string key, bool fips)
  {
      BCEngine bcEngine = new BCEngine(new BlowfishEngine(), _encoding);
      bcEngine.SetPadding(_padding);
      return bcEngine.Encrypt(plain, key);
  }

    public static string Decryption(string cipher, string key, bool fips)
  {
      BCEngine bcEngine = new BCEngine(new BlowfishEngine(), _encoding);
      bcEngine.SetPadding(_padding);
      return bcEngine.Decrypt(cipher, key);
  }
```

Exeption:

```
Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.CryptoException was unhandled
    Message=last block incomplete in decryption
   Source=ID_Serwer
   StackTrace:
        at BlowFishCS.BCEngine.BouncyCastleCrypto(Boolean forEncrypt, Byte[] input, String  key) in C:\Documents and Settings\WirtualOS\Pulpit\serever\ID_Serwer\Blowfish.cs:line 96
       at BlowFishCS.BCEngine.Decrypt(String cipher, String key) in C:\Documents and Settings\WirtualOS\Pulpit\serever\ID_Serwer\Blowfish.cs:line 60
       at ID_Serwer.ID_Serv_Main.Decryption(String cipher, String key, Boolean fips) in C:\Documents and Settings\WirtualOS\Pulpit\serever\ID_Serwer\ID_Serv_Main.cs:line 154
       at ID_Serwer.ID_Serv_Main.process_cmd(String cmd) in C:\Documents and Settings\WirtualOS\Pulpit\serever\ID_Serwer\ID_Serv_Main.cs:line 163
       at ID_Serwer.ID_Serv_Main.Main(String[] args) in C:\Documents and Settings\WirtualOS\Pulpit\serever\ID_Serwer\ID_Serv_Main.cs:line 137
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Exeption is show after that Decryption("test", "HjcWtqDOBMo=", true)

Comment: If you're going to ask for help about an Exception you get, please post the Exception you get.

Comment: Program crashes and show this message last block incomplete in decryption in visual studio 2010 Express ;P

Comment: You need to show the exception, [here is a good example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596510/getting-exception), otherwise nobody has ANY idea whats wrong.

Comment: Any reason you're using blowfish over AES?

Comment: No, but with AES it's that same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
static Encoding _encoding = Encoding.ASCII;

return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
```

You should use the same encoding in encrypt and decrypt.

Update: Use `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` to support not ASCII characters.

Comment: Ok, I change Encoding.ASCII to Encoding.Unicode.
Where i should add/change return Convert.ToBase64String(result); ?

Comment: Try to use everywhere _encoding.GetBytes and _encoding.GetString.

Comment: Exeption it's only Decrypt funcion, when i change  Convert.FromBase64String(cipher) to _encoding.GetBytes(cipher) exeption message pad block corrupted